# What is the best currency API out there?

Tags: php, api, server-side-scripting

I may be asking an odd question, but webmasters seem like a decent place to post this.

I'm in the search for an accurate, easy API (such as using JSON or XML) so I can use my web application.

I've been trying Google's *secret* API, but it's dependency isn't that good because of parsing the string (weird JSON format that PHP sometimes return incorrect data or truncates the string due to parsing error, but Google's API is fair but can be improved.

So, all I'm asking is your current best currency API out there, I want to have them to include documented API so I can use it with PHP.

Cheers.

Comment: Do you mean API or datasource?

Comment: Had the same issue. ECB did not provide sufficient data for me, and XE was simply too expensive. Check out https://currencylayer.com - they seem most suitable for Startups, and offer a Free Plan without any obligations or time limits...

Answer (score 4):

We looked at this for an implementation earlier this year. We considered 2:

**European Central Bank**

- [refer : ECB](http://www.ecb.int/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html)
- free
- lists exchange rates against the Euro
- Limited number of currencies

**XE**

- [refer : XE](http://www.xe.com/dfs/product.php)
- USD540 a year for daily lookups
- available for a variety of base currencies
- very wide currency support

In the end, we went with XE, as we needed to support some currencies the ECB didn't have.